# I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when i try to run the word count example in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run the word count example from the Spark website (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) in Scala Spark but when I try to spark-submit I get an exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize
The Spark version is 2.0.1 and the Scala version is 2.12.0

The full trace is here: http://pastebin.com/LEjRTAy4

The example code works fine on spark-shell

Comment: The pertinent message from your stack trace is "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize".

Comment: Can you try after changing Scala compiler version from 2.12 to 2.11?

Comment: @Asrinivas Yes you are right this worked. Thanks a lot.
The only thing i had to do is to change the Scala version to 2.11 on the sbt file.

Answer (score 1):

http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

Note: Starting version 2.0, Spark is built with Scala 2.11 by default. Scala 2.10 users should download the Spark source package and build with Scala 2.10 support.

use scala 2.11.11